# Writing CSV file as hive tables - Zero after decimal not loading in tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a CSV file and I'm reading the CSV as data frame and writing back as hive table. I'm defining the schema definitions in the code as well.For example:

```py
StructType([
    StructField("name",StringType(), True),
    StructField("amount",DecimalType(5,2), True)])
```

Certain column in CSV file are decimal type.Hence as mentioned above in the schema definition I have used decimal type along with precision (5,2).

But however for values like example 12.56 in CSV is getting copied to hive table as 12.56 But the problem is for values that has zeroes after decimal point like 15.00 in CSV it is writing into hive table as 15 removing the zeroes after decimal point

I have gone through Various hive documents and found that this was a issue back in hive version 0.12 - 0.14. And it was solved later versions by mentioning the precision and scale.

Currently I'm mentioning precision and scale also my hive version is 1.2.

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: 12 and 12.00 are same.  Why do you need 12.00 ? Do you have any specific reason?

Comment: This what hive does.  For example - `select cast(15.00 as decimal(5,2))` returns 15.